# How to find the path of a specific application (Google Chrome)?

Tags: google-chrome, executable, paths

I have Google Chrome downloaded on my laptop and I want to find where it is compared to a Windows path use it, basically for a text to speech project.

On Windows it is located here :

```
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
```

How can I get the path on Linux? I tried:

```
(MoodBotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/moodbot$ which chrome
(MoodBotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/moodbot$ which google*
(MoodBotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/moodbot$ where google*
No command 'where' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gwhere' from package 'gwhere' (universe)
where: command not found
```

And the "Search your computer" top left button doesn't provide the path as well.

Comment: How did you install it? How do you start it usually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have installed the stable version of Google Chrome, run the following commands to find its location

```
whereis google-chrome-stable
```

or

```
which google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: Ho great! But that gives two results:  `google-chrome-stable: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/share/man/man1/google-chrome-stable.1.gz` for the first one and `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`for the second

Comment: That means the executable `google-chrome-stable` is located at `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: TBH `whereis` is IMVHO a bad idea, you can get results that are barely relevant at all.